# Set proper gap between text.view frame and button frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, textview, cgrect

I have a text view and buttons. For some reason i got unexpected result when trying to set proper gap between those 2 elements. I think there could be incorrect calculating of text.view frame. That is how i manage to set text.view frame:

```
//1 Setting properties for text, starting with dictionary containing font size and family
    NSDictionary *stringAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIFont fontWithName:@"helvetica neue"
                                                                                        size:14]
                                                                 forKey: NSFontAttributeName];

    //Creating frame to hold textView
    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(self.myTextView.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX);
    CGSize textViewSize = [self.descriptionStringShort boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize
                                                                    options:NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine|NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                                 attributes:stringAttributes context:nil].size;

    //Setting frame
    CGRect frame = self.myTextView.frame;
    frame.size.height = textViewSize.height;

    NSLog(@"%f height", frame.size.height);
    self.myTextView.frame = frame;
```

After that, when tried to set button frames it always show different gap between those to elements (my "rough" solutions is to check height of text.view and set "minimum" and "maximum" y depend on it, but it won't work in a real world app). For example, button frame may be draw on textView.frame or much below it. There is how i set map frame:

```
CGRect mapButtonFrame = self.mapButton.frame;
    mapButtonFrame.origin.x = 30;

    if (frame.size.height < 50){
    mapButtonFrame.origin.y = (200+frame.size.height + 150);
    }   else  if (frame.size.height >300){
        mapButtonFrame.origin.y = (200+frame.size.height +50);
    }   else {
        mapButtonFrame.origin.y = (200+frame.size.height +100);
    }
    self.mapButton.frame = mapButtonFrame;
```

Still, that approach is bad, please take a look at screenshots attached:
[image]

[image]

Here, as you can see, always different gap between 2 elements. How could i make it fixed? 
By the way, auto layout is turned off.
Any advice would be appreciated, thanks1

Comment: Did you consider using AutoLayout?

Comment: No, thanks for mention it, i edit post.

Comment: Well first, i think your font should be spelled `HelveticaNeue`. `helvetica neue` will just give you system font.

Answer (score 1):

This should work just fine:

```
[myTextView sizeToFit];//This will change the textView frame according to the text length

CGRect bFrame = self.mapButton.frame;
bFrame.origin.y = myTextView.frame.size.height + 20.0f;// The gap you want between the text and the button
self.mapButton.frame = bFrame;
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't help (it draw map on textView frame)

Comment: Where do you want the map to be exactly ?

Comment: Don't care really, just below specific (fixed) points below text.view frame (that frame have different size every time, because it contain different text each time it loaded).

Comment: If I understand correctly, there is a view (the map) between the text and the button. Correct?

Comment: No ayu, just textVIew frame and buttons (as pointed on screenshots)

Comment: Well my original answer should work I tested it the must be something else that breaks it. Remove all code and keep only what's on my answer, and set the text of course.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61835/discussion-between-ayu-and-evgeniy-kleban).